# Why cant I clone repository from GitHub

Tags: github, git-clone

I cant clone anything from GitHub.Every time I add my credentials, instead of bein able to clone the repository as normal, I get a message that says that

```
This is not a  valid repository
```

and then message below as well.

```
Command: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks
ls-remote https://github.com/lindar-joy/mrq-wallet.git
```

Output:
Error: Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.

I have tried the advice I found here, without any success:

https://github.community/t/git-clone-is-not-working-for-a-private-repo/501/3

Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: I think you need to show exactly what you are doing: how you are adding credentials, the exact command you are using to clone.  If you can't clone _anything_, then an example using a public repo would be better.

Comment: The repos I am trying to clone are private but I have full access to them. I am trying through SourceTree and from a terminal

Comment: So where it says "This is not a valid source path / URL", what does it say if you hover over or click on "Details"?

Comment: Command: git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks ls-remote https://github.com/****r-bank/bank-manager.git
Output: 
Error: Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to bypass the issue by using Github Desktop

Answer (score 1):

Do this (from inside Git Bash):

```
git credential-manager uninstall
```

then:

```
git credential-manager install
```

It may complain - for me it complained on both steps that it failed, but it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for some time now but everything got fixed once I installed the new git version on my system.

Just visit this link
https://gitforwindows.org/